# problem_ldap_bind

Tags: unix, ldap, openldap

contents of file.ldif

```
(le file.ldif)
dn: dc=ircoms,dc=com
changetype: add
objectclass: top
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: ircoms
dc: ircoms

dn: ou=People,dc=ircoms,dc=com
changetype: add
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: People

dn: ou=Group,dc=ircoms,dc=com
changetype: add
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: Group

dn: ou=addressbook,dc=ircoms,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: addressbook
```

I followed some advises on this site, but didn't get some interesting things:

```
$ usr/sbin/slapd -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
$ ldapadd -x -D 'cn=Manager,dc=ircoms,dc=com' -f file.ldif -W
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

[root@bob openldap]# /etc/init.d/slapd start
Starting slapd (via systemctl): [ OK ]

$ ldapadd -x -D 'cn=Manager,dc=ircoms,dc=com' -f file.ldif -W
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

content of /etc/openldap

```
cacerts file.ldif ldap.conf schema slapd.conf slapd.d.bak
```

containts of /var/lib/ldap

```
DB_CONFIG
```

I still get:

```
Enter LDAP Password:  
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

Comment: If this is additional information for your other question, please state it there. Otherwise, please learn howo to use the formatting tools offered to you, so that we can read your question more easily.

Comment: Where and how did you set your LDAP password? It doesn't set itself magically.

Comment: Is `cn=Manager,dc=ircoms,dc=com` defined in your slapd.conf as `rootdn`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to follow a step-by-step tutorial in setting up OpenLDAP that is written for your skill level and operating system.

As SvenW noted, you don't set the password anywhere. If you don't set the password, you cannot authenticate. Then your possibilities are to either a) allow unauthenticated write access or b) use `slapadd(8)` when `slapd` isn't running.